# Excel adding double-quotes to a TSV file

Tags: excel

I'm working on a system that primarily uses TSV files for internal exports, and many of the users who interact with the files only currently use Excel.

I've noticed lately that if a cell contains a comma character:  when the TSV is downloaded that cell looks fine, but then if the document is opened, changed in any way and then is closed again: then quote characters are being added around that cell.

So if the file contained the text !house, pm and then the file was in any way amended and saved:  that cell would now contain "!house, pm"

Re-importing with the " characters is causing errors all over the place.

Couple Q's:

- Is there a way to stop Excel from adding these "" characters?
- If not:  is there a better program to be using to amend this doc, with similar functionality and format to Excel (especially for non-technical users)?  So like a row+column layout, ability to filter, etc?

Comment: For the first question, I'm not aware of one, and the second question is off topic for StackOverflow (more specifically, tools recommendation is off topic).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Yes, saving the TSV file from Excel adds the quote marks around comma-containing fields.  But when re-importing it into Excel, since the quote mark is set as the text qualifier, the quote marks are not present.  What "errors all over the place" are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry Ron I should have specified:  rather than Excel erroring, the system I am re-importing the TSV into isn't parsing out the " characters.  I've asked the team to work around it by opening the TSV in a text editor and replacing the " characters, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score -2):

Libre office does not have this issue.

Comment: That's great, but... this question has nothing to do with Libre Office (and this really isn't the place to promote a product or service). Please refrain from posting promotion-style answers (also, what you posted isn't an answer, as it doesn't address anything included in the OP's question).